# How do I add multiple key and values to an object from a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an object

```
var foo = {
    "prop1" : "value2",
    "prop2" : "value3",
    "prop3" : "value4"
};
```

and i'd love a way to have a function which would allow one to input multiple key and value pairs at once.

Right now I have this:

```
function propAndValAdder(){
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        foo[arguments[i]] = [arguments[i + 1]];
    }
}
```

Is this right?

Comment: [`Object.defineProperties()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)

Comment: `foo[arguments[i]] = [arguments[++i]];`

Comment: foo[arguments[i]] = arguments[++i];    (get rid of one set of [])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right: just have to change the loop to add 2 to 'i' (so that you don't add the value as another property, have to skip it) and get rid of the []'s around the value in the assignment line (this is making the value an array which we don't want).

Corrected code:

```
var foo = {
    "prop1" : "value2",
    "prop2" : "value3",
    "prop3" : "value4"
};

function propAndValAdder(){
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i+=2) {
        foo[arguments[i]] = arguments[i + 1];
    }
}

propAndValAdder("prop4","value5","prop5","value6");
console.log(foo);
```

// Object { prop1: "value2", prop2: "value3", prop3: "value4", prop4: "value4", prop5: "value6" }

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your information in the parameters and fix your loop.

Corrected version  :

```
   /**
 * Add properties and values to the object
 * @param  {array} arguments An array where even are keys and odd are the values
 * @param  {object} obj       [null] The object to add properties
 * @return {obj}           Return the object but not nessary since it's an object(references)
 */
function propAndValAdder(arguments,obj) {
    if (!obj) obj = {};
    if (arguments.join) //We valid this is an array
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 2)
        obj[arguments[i]] = arguments[i + 1];
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: I think I would conceptually reverse the signature.  Probably something more like foo(obj /*, args */)  and then in the body capture the array of additional arguments with something like function var args = Array.from(arguments).slice(1)

Comment: You have to remove the []'s around [arguments[i + 1]]; or you end up assigning a one-element array